# Netlogo - Iterating through patch list and writing each output to a row in a list

Tags: netlogo

I have a list of cells `destination_cells`, and am trying to loop through each cell and count the number of turtles and the average weight of the turtles in each. For each cell, I want to write the cell's ID (which I am assuming is just `destination_cells` as coordinates) and the two variables to a list `cell_list`. I think my confusion stems from not understanding how to use anonymous reporters in foreach. If I replace 'next cell' with `destination_cells` in the foreach block, I get, for example, the same `total_turtle_in_destination_cells` value for every single cell in `destination_cells`. The same occurs with using `next_cells` in the block. Where am I making a mistake?

```
set destination_cells [self] of patches with [ any? turtles-here]

foreach destination_cells [next_cell -> ask next_cell 
[
  ; Counts number of turtles in each cell
  set total_turtle_in_destination count turtles-on destination_cells 
  
  ; Finds average weight of turtles in each cell
  set avg_weight_turtle_in_destination mean [mass] of turtles-on destination_cells
]

    set cell_list lput (csv:to-row (list
    destination_cells
    total_turtle_in_destination
    avg_weight_turtle_in_destination
    )) cell_events_list

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative that:

Makes a reporter to get the info desired (the patch info as patch x and y, the total turtles on a patch, the mean weight of present turtles) from whatever patch that calls the reporter

Updates the info list directly by querying the destination_cells

```
turtles-own [ weight ]
globals [ destination_cells cell_info_list]

to setup
  ca
  resize-world 0 5 0 5
  set-patch-size 30
  reset-ticks
  
  crt 20 [
    set weight random 10 + 1
    move-to one-of patches
  ]
end

to-report report-self-info
  let n_turtles_here count turtles-here
  let mean_weight mean [weight] of turtles-here
  report (list self n_turtles_here mean_weight)
end

to create-info-list 
  set destination_cells patches with [ any? turtles-here]
  set cell_info_list [report-self-info] of destination_cells
  print cell_info_list
end
```

In response to your question "how can the patch call the reporter? I tried `ask destination_cell [report-self-info]`, but a command is expected":

When you make a `to-report` procedure with the structure like the above that uses `self`, it's somewhat like a `turtles-own` or `patches-own` variable. In this case, you can call it just as you would have a `turtle` variable like `color` or `xcor` or a `patch` variable like `pcolor` or `pxcor`- if you run something like:

```
ask one-of patches [ print report-self-info ]
```

You should get something *like*

```
[(patch 5 2) 2 7.5]
```

This is why the `set cell_info_list [report-self-info] of destination_cells` above works- because you could do something like `set cell_info_list [pcolor] of destination_cells` in a similar way.

Comment: how can the patch call the reporter? I tried ```ask destination_cell [report-self-info]```, but a command is expected. Thanks!

Comment: @P_Grace - I have edited the answer to address this question.